# Why doesn’t java.util.Collection define next(), hasNext() directly?

Tags: java, collections, iterator

If *Collection* defines *hasNext()* instead of *iterator().hasNext()*, we could write loop easier:

```
while(collection.hasNext()){…}
```

instead of:

```
Iterator it= collection.iterator();
While(it.hasNext()){…}
```

Of course, I know easy way for loop `for(E e:collection)` exists.

Why interface Iterator exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would not be **thread safe**. The collection would only be able to maintain one "current position" so you couldn't iterate over it simultaneously in two different threads.

Having iterators allows multiple simultaneous iterating threads that don't step on each others' toes.

Comment: ...as long as they don't modify the collection they are pointing to.  In the latter case, a ConcurrentModificationException will be thrown.

Answer (score 9):

Because you can have multiple valid `Iterator` objects for the same `Collection` object simultaneously.

This can be useful.  If `Collection` defined the `next` and `hasNext` methods, this approach would be precluded.

Comment: Multiple Iterator? Could you offer an example?

Comment: Shengyuan Lu: Multiple iterators could come about by using threads as John Kugelman points out in his answer.

Comment: There are also cases where you would want more than one `Iterator` from a single thread.  Any data structure where you need a lookbehind, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that the rationale for having iterators factored out of the collection is so that there can be many **kinds** of them (other than simply moving forward through the collection). You can create your own iterator to go backwards or do something like iterate through a DOM graph visiting all of the nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Primary reason is the collection would have to have iteration "state".  You couldn't support multiple iterations at the same time.  PHP arrays have something like built in iteration state and it confused me.